# What incorrect Metadata-Flavor header at GoogleAuth means?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I´m trying to write to firestore from a onCall firebase function

## functions.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp();



console.log('initialing functions at ' , new Date().toString())


exports.getLinks = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onCall( (data,context) => {

    console.log('starting to get links ' , new Date().toString())
    console.log('data' , data.query, data.limit, data.country, data.uid)
    console.log('context auth', context.auth, 'context.auth.uid', context.auth.uid)
    // is there anything like admin.setCredentials(context.auth) necessary here?
    const queries = admin.firestore().collection('queries');
    let uid = data.uid
    console.log('uid', uid);
    console.log('queries ref', queries)
    //probably when trying to write here is not being allowed
    queries.doc(uid).set({LinksArrayLength: 'starting'})
        .then( r => console.log('writing to firestore 1 result', r))
        .catch( err => console.error('writing to firestore 2 error', err))
```

The console output is like this

> starting to get links  Fri May 31 2019 19:01:10 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)
>
> > data sells anywhere 2 com fwfwqe
> >      context auth {
> >        uid: 'f23oij2ioafOIJOeofiwjOIJ',
> >        token: {
> >          iss: 'https://securetoken.google.com/was98oinr-fa4c9',
> >          aud: 'was234r-f32c9',
> >          auth_time: 1559327744,
> >          user_id: 'f23oij2ioafOIJOeofiwjOIJ',
> >          sub: 'f23oij2ioafOIJOeofiwjOIJ',
> >          iat: 1559338208,
> >          exp: 1559341808,
> >          email: 'awef3h@gmail.com',
> >          email_verified: false,
> >          firebase: { identities: [Object], sign_in_provider: 'password' },
> >          uid: 'f23oij2ioafOIJOeofiwjOIJ'
> >        }
> >      } context.auth.uid f23oij2ioafOIJOeofiwjOIJ
> >      uid f1EMxzwjJlTaH3u7RAYsySx0MZV2
> >      queries ref CollectionReference {
> >        _firestore: Firestore {
> >          _settings: {
> >            projectId: 'xxx',
> >            firebaseVersion: '7.0.0',
> >            libName: 'gccl',
> >            libVersion: '1.3.0 fire/7.0.0'
> >          },

## and then the not allowed write request to firestore ?

```
writing to firestore 2 error Error: Unexpected error determining execution environment: Invalid response from metadata service: incorrect Metadata-Flavor header.
>      at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (H:\nprojetos\whats_app_sender\firebase_sender\vue_sender\wa_sender\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:164:23)
>      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
>      at rejected (H:\nprojetos\whats_app_sender\firebase_sender\vue_sender\wa_sender\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:20:65)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

How could I ensure that the request.auth.uid is being sent to the firestore write request?

## Firestore rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;//: if request.auth.uid != null;
// even when commented and allowing all requests still giving the error //message
    }
  }
}
```

Even when fully allowed is continues to give the error.

I´m trying to write to firestore to update the client side when something is being written to the the collections('queries') ... so that the  client gets notified of the function progress...
Is there is a better way of doing that also?

On the client side the code goes like this

## client-side

```
fireApp.firestore().collection('queries').doc(this.getUser.uid).onSnapshot(snap => {
                    debugger
                    console.log('snap', snap)

                    snap.exists ?
                    snap.docChanges().forEach(async change => {
                        if (change.type === "modified") {
                         _vue.updating = true // the function is in progress
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved
It just required propper initialization

```
const credential = require('./xxxxx.json')

admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(credential),
databaseURL: "https://xxx.xxx.firebaseio.com"
});
```

this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z87OZtIYC_0)
explains how to initialize it properly